# How do I define sections for a custom beamer class in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, beamer

When I try to make a custom beamer class for Org-mode [by manipulating `org-export-latex-classes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943432/789593) I do something like:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
             '("mybeamer"
               "\\documentclass{beamer}
               \\usepackage{...}
               [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
               [NO-PACKAGES]
               [EXTRA]"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Obviously this does not work well with beamer because it structures content in other ways than by sections. How can I make Org-mode work with the way beamer structures content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `org-beamer-sectioning` instead of setting section by hand. So to make a custom beamer class for Org-mode which can be used via `#+LaTeX_CLASS: mybeamer` by putting something of the following form in your .emacs:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
             '("mybeamer"
               "\\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
               \\usepackage{...}
               [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
               [NO-PACKAGES]
               [EXTRA]
               [BEAMER-HEADER-EXTRA]"
               org-beamer-sectioning))
```

This requires (as for all manipulations of `org-export-latex-classes`) the following in your .emacs to work:

```lisp
(require 'org-latex)
```